# AlarmManager setExact() sends early

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an app that sends notifucation from a database SQLite and on some devices it send the alarm earlier than intended, some on time and some late
Is that problem with the device?

Comment: what flag are you passing?

Comment: FLAG_ONE_SHOT bcz i dont want it to get previous alarm

Comment: I don't think you got my question, i meant on setExact, not the flag in pendingIntent

Comment: Where should this be in the code?

Comment: Do you mean RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: yup RTC_WAKEUP or RTC, they are arguments for setExact's first parameter

Comment: Mine is RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: yeah no prob, so replace FLAG_ONE_SHOT by FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and make sure you are giving it a correct timestamp to setExact because everything seems correct